# Creating a Label column in R for the unnamed variables

Tags: r, dataframe, label

I want to create a column called Label to display in my summary statistics. For example, something like the table below.

[image]

Suppose I have this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(age_years = c(33, 11, 45, 67, 8, 99), sex = factor(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)))

> df

      age_years       sex
    1          33          0
    2          11          1
    3          45          1
    4          67          0
    5          8           0
    6          99          0
```

I tried using `Hmisc` package.

```
library(Hmisc)

var.labels = c(age_years="Age in Years", sex="Sex")

label(df) = as.list(var.labels[match(names(df), names(var.labels))])
```

And for the summary table, I used the following codes:

```
Variables <- names(df)
Label <- label(df)
Missing <- sapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
Type <- sapply(df, function(x) class(x))
Min <- sapply(df, function(x) min(x, na.rm = TRUE))
Max <- sapply(df, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
SD <- sapply(df, function(x) format(round(sd(x, na.rm=TRUE), 2), nsmall = 2))
Mean <- sapply(df, function(x) format(round(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), 2), nsmall = 2))
#To get the Latex table for the rows 
knitr::kable(as.data.frame(cbind(Variables, Label, Missing, Type, Min, Max, Mean, SD), row.names = FALSE), "latex")
```

I am not getting a column called "Label" with the above codes. I want to have the variable age_years be labeled "Age in Years" in the Label column of the summary statistics table, and the same thing for the sex variable. I am getting this latex output from R.

```
   \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
\hline
Variables & Missing & age\_years & sex & Min & Max & Mean & SD\\
\hline
age\_years & 0 & labelled & labelled & 0 & 104 & 54.94 & 20.06\\
\hline
sex & 0 & numeric & numeric & 1 & 2 & 1.46 & 0.50\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

My Latex table doesn't look like the one above:

[image]

I am not sure why the age_years and sex are appearing as columns.  I want to get rid of these variable columns.

I think there is something wrong with this part of the code`Label <- label(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have more than one value in a `class`, for example see :

```
class(df$age_years)
#[1] "labelled" "numeric"
```

Combine the classes into one comma-separated string.

```
toString(class(df$age_years))
#[1] "labelled, numeric"
```

Or if you want to select the second class ("numeric") you can use `if` condition.

```
if(length(class(df$age_years) > 1)) class(df$age_years)[2] else class(df$age_years)[1]
#[1] "numeric"
```

Complete code using the `if` approach -

```
df <- Filter(is.numeric, df)
Variables <- names(df)
Label <- label(df)
Missing <- sapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
Type <- sapply(df, function(x) {tmp <- class(x);if(length(x) > 1) tmp[2] else tmp[1]})
Min <- sapply(df, function(x) min(x, na.rm = TRUE))
Max <- sapply(df, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
SD <- sapply(df, function(x) format(round(sd(x, na.rm=TRUE), 2), nsmall = 2))
Mean <- sapply(df, function(x) format(round(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), 2), nsmall = 2))
#To get the Latex table for the rows 
knitr::kable(data.frame(Variables, Label, Missing, Type, Min, Max, Mean, SD, row.names = NULL))

|Variables |Label        | Missing|Type    | Min| Max|Mean  |SD    |
|:---------|:------------|-------:|:-------|---:|---:|:-----|:-----|
|age_years |Age in Years |       0|numeric |   8|  99|43.83 |34.82 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the output that I am getting doesn't have the labels. For age_years variables the label comes out as the name of the variable itself and same for sex. I want to label them as "Age in Years" and "Sex" respectively in the Label column. Basically what I was trying here ``var.labels = c(age_years="Age in Years", sex="Sex")
``

Comment: The Label column is just to indicate the Variable Description, basically. I want to create a similar table like the first table.

Comment: I see the labels in column called `Label`. I have updated the answer with the output I am getting. Which part of the output do you don't want/change?

Comment: Yes, I see that the Label column on your output shows "Age in Years" and that is exactly what I am looking for. However, in the Type column, I just want one type, i.e., "numeric". Don't want to include "labeled" as a type. I am not sure if I should use ``string toString(class(x))`` under Type.

Comment: For that you need to use `if`/`else` approach. I have updated the answer to include that.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with only character variables as well. I also have character variables in the dataset but they are not included in the table. For character variables, I just want the label, missing, and type. Other statistics aren't that meaningful for character variables.

Comment: I see that you have asked a new question for that. I'll comment there.