# Error message for a subset of dataframe: number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to get a summary table for a subset of the variables in my dataframe. The subset focuses on numeric variables only. So I created a subset with only numeric variables and calling the subset as numtable. However I am getting an error message:

```
Warning message:
In cbind(Variables, Missing, Type, Min, Max, Mean, SD) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

Here are the codes:

```
#Summary of the numeric variables in the dataset
numvars <- names(df) %in% c("age_years", "sex", "sop1", "servcode", "los", "admt", "ptstatus", "msdrg",
                            "msmdc", "sm_er", "diagnosis_order1", "diagnosis_order2", "diagnosis_order3", "diagnosis_order4", "diagnosis_order5",
                            "diagnosis_order1", "diagnosis_order1", "diagnosis_order1", "diagnosis_order1", "diagnosis_order1", "diagnosis_order1", 
                            "diagnosis_order6", "diagnosis_order7", "diagnosis_order8", "diagnosis_order9", "diagnosis_order10", "diagnosis_order11", "diagnosis_order12",
                            "diagnosis_order13", "diagnosis_order14", "diagnosis_order15", "diagnosis_order16", "diagnosis_order17", "diagnosis_order18", "diagnosis_order19", 
                            "diagnosis_order20" ,"diagnosis_order21", "diagnosis_order22", "diagnosis_order23", "diagnosis_order24", "diagnosis_order25", "diagnosis_order26", 
                            "diagnosis_order27", "diagnosis_order28", "diagnosis_order29", "diagnosis_order30", "diagnosis_order31", "diagnosis_order32", "diagnosis_order33", 
                            "diagnosis_order34", "diagnosis_order35")
numtable <- df[numvars]
Variables <- names(numtable)
Missing <- sapply(numtable, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
Type <- sapply(numtable, function(x) class(x))
Min <- sapply(numtable, function(x) min(x, na.rm = TRUE))
Max <- sapply(numtable, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
SD <- sapply(numtable, function(x) format(round(sd(x, na.rm=TRUE), 2), nsmall = 2))
Mean <- sapply(numtable, function(x) format(round(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), 2), nsmall = 2))
#To get the simple table
knitr::kable(as.data.frame(cbind(Variables, Missing, Type, Min, Max, Mean, SD), row.names = FALSE))
#To get the Latex table for the rows 
knitr::kable(as.data.frame(cbind(Variables, Missing, Type, Min, Max, Mean, SD), row.names = FALSE), "latex")
```

Suppose I have this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(age_years = c(33, 11, 45, 67, 8, 99), sex = factor(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)))

    > df
    
          age_years       sex
        1          33          0
        2          11          1
        3          45          1
        4          67          0
        5          8           0
        6          99          0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that one of the variable that you have manually selected is not numeric. What does `Type` return? Do all of them return numeric?

Also you can select the variables dynamically instead of manually selecting them which may lead to errors. Try this approach :

```
df <- type.convert(df)
numtable <- Filter(is.numeric, df)
Variables <- names(numtable)
Missing <- sapply(numtable, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
Type <- sapply(numtable, function(x) class(x))
Min <- sapply(numtable, function(x) min(x, na.rm = TRUE))
Max <- sapply(numtable, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
SD <- sapply(numtable, function(x) format(round(sd(x, na.rm=TRUE), 2), nsmall = 2))
Mean <- sapply(numtable, function(x) format(round(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), 2), nsmall = 2))
#To get the simple table
knitr::kable(data.frame(Variables, Missing, Type, Min, Max, Mean, SD))
#To get the Latex table for the rows 
knitr::kable(data.frame(Variables, Missing, Type, Min, Max, Mean, SD), "latex")
```

Comment: Hi, yes all of them return numeric. In the table, I want to include Type as a column showing the type of a variable.

Comment: Then my guess is wrong. Do you get the same error when you use my answer? I tried with `df <- mtcars` and both your code and mine work. Can you provide sample of your dataset with `dput(df)` ?

Comment: No, I don't get any error when I use your answer. But I instead of numeric I am getting integer as type for variables.

Comment: So that is what their `class` is.

Comment: I am doing the same thing character variables as well, actually. The type to indicate whether the variable is a character or numeric.

Comment: Hmmm....Can you provide a small example dataset for us to work with?

Comment: I added a small example dataset with age_years and sex. It from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66647156/creating-a-label-column-in-r-for-the-unnamed-variables

Comment: Actually I figured it out and accepted your answer. If I exclude ``df <- type.convert(df)`` of your answer then it is fine. I get the output as numeric instead of integers and there are no errors. Btw could you help me with this question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66647156/creating-a-label-column-in-r-for-the-unnamed-variables.